# VichUploaderBundle and Symfony: get exif from JPG

Tags: symfony, exif, vichuploaderbundle

I am using Symfony 5 with the excellent VichUploaderBundle to upload pictures.
I'am trying to get the exif informations from jpeg files.
I use the function exif_read_data and it's ok(my test is working).

Now i am wondering when is it the best way to save the exif information in my entity please?

I have an entity "Picture" with the traditionnal ImageFile, filename,...

I'am quite new to this and i don't know what to do.

I added an exif field and setExif to my entity to try to save it as the time as the entity is persisting but it's not working.
Is it better to call a listener after the entity is created and then make another persist to save exif informations?
Or maybe modify the UploadableField with adding an option of Exif (we already have the size, original filename,...) but i think it's clearly not the best.

For now i have this (when i upload my picture) but it's not working:

My Picture entity looks like this:

```
  /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $exif_file = [];

    public function setImageFile(?File $imageFile = null): void
    {
        $this->imageFile = $imageFile;

        if (null !== $imageFile) {
            $this->updated_at = new \DateTimeImmutable("now",new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
        }
    }

    public function setExifFile(?array $exif_file): self
    {
        $this->exif_file = $exif_file;
        return $this;
    }
```

My form is in another entity (A), and my upload is defined like this:

```
->add('pictureFiles', FileType::class,[
                'required'=>false,
                'multiple'=>true,
            ])
```

This A entity has:

```
public function setPictureFiles($pictureFiles): self
    {
        foreach ($pictureFiles as $pictureFile) {

            $picture = new Picture();
            $picture->setImageFile($pictureFile);

           $path = 'http://mywebsite'.$this->helper->asset($picture->getImageFile(), 'imageFile');

            $exif_file = exif_read_data($path,null,true)['FILE'];

            $picture->setExifFile($exif_file);

            $this->addPicture($picture);
        }
        $this->pictureFiles = $pictureFiles;
        return $this;
    }
```

The problem is that i can't succeed to get the filepath.

I tried different ways but without success.

When the entity is created it's working by doing this: `$this->helper->asset($picture, 'imageFile');`

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hi, it will be nice if you will show the Picture entity code. And also, to set some field while persisting or updating Entity you can use [Doctrine events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Sorry bad movement with the keyboard, i updated my question with the code.
Yes i think listener is the best idea but i wanted to know if it's possible to insert it right in the same time as the whole entity. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, you don't need listener for that here. Check my link in comment before. You can use doctrine events in annotations for method in the Entity class

Comment: ok, i thought it was listeners too but it i will go to check it carefully, thank you very much